# WCF restful WebMessageFormat.Json

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I have  a problem. Here simple WCF restful service and he doesn't want to response with JSON format although I specify `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`. He always responses with XMLformat: `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GoalTracker.WcfRestService"`

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<GoalTrackerDb>(new GoalTrackerInitializer());
        RegisterRoutes();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
    }
}    

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "TestPatient",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        Method = "GET")]
    List<Patient> GetCollection();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "TestPatient/{id}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        Method = "GET")]
    TestPatient Get(string id);
}


[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
        GoalTrackerDb db = new GoalTrackerDb();
        public List<Patient> GetCollection()
        {
            var result = db.Patients.ToList();
            return result;
        }
        public TestPatient Get(string id)
        {
            TestPatient testpat = new TestPatient();
            return testpat;
        }
  }

public class TestPatient
{

    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TestGoal> Goals { get; set; }

    public TestPatient()
    {
        ID = 0;
        Email = "ads@mail.com";
        FirstName = "janmbo";
        LastName = "Ayo";
        Goals = new Collection<TestGoal>();
        Goals.Add(new TestGoal());
        Goals.Add(new TestGoal());
    }
}


public class TestGoal
{

    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string GoalName { get; set; }

    public TestGoal()
    {
        ID = 2;
        GoalName = "SomeGoalName";
    }
}
```

Comment: Change it to `WebMessageFormat.Xml` maybe?

Comment: No, need Json  format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most probably because of misleading [`WebHttpEndpoint.AutomaticFormatSelectionEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpendpoint.automaticformatselectionenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> When automatic format selection is enabled, the WCF infrastructure parses the **Accept header** of the request message and determines the most appropriate response format. If the Accept header does not specify a suitable response format, the WCF infrastructure uses the **Content-Type** of the request message or the default response format of the operation.

So if you call this service with `Accept: application/xml` or similar, `WebMessageFormat.Json` will be silently ignored. You can set it within `system.serviceModel` section:

```
<standardEndpoints>
   <webHttpEndpoint>
      <standardEndpoint automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" />
   </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```